# Jest - mock `config` module

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs

I'm writing a unit test where I want to mock the value returned when calling `config`.

In the module I call config several times, and want to mock the returned value from one of the calls:

```
import config from 'config';

const REGION: string = config.get('AWS_DYNAMODB_REGION');
const ENDPOINTS: (string | undefined)[] = config.get('AWS_DYNAMODB_ENDPOINTS');
const CLIENT_TIMEOUT: number = config.get('AWS_DYNAMODB_CLIENT_TIMEOUT');
```

How can I mock the returned value for `config.get('AWS_DYNAMODB_CLIENT_TIMEOUT')` for example.

Please advise.

Comment: How did you import `config` module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved in the following way:

```
jest.mock('config');
import config from 'config';

let configGetSpy: jest.SpyInstance;

configGetSpy = jest.spyOn(config, 'get');
    configGetSpy
      .mockReturnValueOnce('AWS_DYNAMODB_REGION')
      .mockReturnValueOnce([])
      .mockReturnValueOnce(1001)
      .mockReturnValueOnce(false)
      .mockReturnValueOnce(false);
```